# Ironfan setup problems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra

I’m trying (and failing!) to set up ironfan

I’m getting to the situadion where I’ve installed it, but when I do a ‘knife cluster list’ I get the following error:

> ERROR: Gem::LoadError: Unable to activate ironfan-3.1.5, because fog-0.8.2 conflicts with fog (~> 1.2.0)

I have fog 1.2.0 and 0.8.2 installed. I tried the obvious thing of uninstalling 0.8.2 but then get the following error that it can’t find fog 0.8.2:

> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ironfan-3.1.5/lib/ironfan.rb:34:in cluster_path': undefined methodmap' for "/home/steve/poc/chef/chef-repo/cookbooks":String (NoMethodError)

If I install only 0.8.2 I get the original message:

> ```
> ERROR: Gem::LoadError: Unable to activate ironfan-3.1.5, because fog-0.8.2 conflicts with fog (~> 1.2.0)
> ```

I’m running ruby 1.9.3p125 and gem 1.8.11 on Centos. Any help would be appreciated. fog 0.8.2 is required by knife-ec2 and I need to run both.

EDIT: I found the answer. I needed to edit the gemspec to allow greater versions of fog. See https://github.com/infochimps-labs/ironfan/issues/130

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :) It's okay to answer your own question and mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I needed to edit the gemspec to allow greater versions of fog. See https://github.com/infochimps-labs/ironfan/issues/130

Answer (score 0):

Your best idea is to install [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/) and create a gemset to install ironfan:

```
$ rvm gemset create knife-ironfan
$ rvm gemset use knife-ironfan
$ gem install ironfan
$ [do your thing]
```

Creating a gemset limits the scope of installed gems so you can cope with conflicting dependencies.  I've had a spot of trouble with fog at one stage and this works quite well.  In practice it's a bit tricky/annoying to be changing in and out of different gemsets, but you if you have a directory you can work out of you can create a {.rvmrc} to automatically switch to a gemset when you change into that directory.